# Special Infinite series diverging to +infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

If a sequence is neither convergent nor diverges to +(-) infinity. Can series generated by it diverge to +infinity? Is there some example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$a_n=1$ if $n$ even, $a_n=1/2$ if $n$ odd.